# Easeljs Container event listeners

Tags: events, containers, stage, easeljs

I create Container, attach onPress function to it, then add it as Child to the stage.

Then clear the stage ( so there is no such child there anymore ), update it.

but onPress is still working.

Comment: solved it, I recreated stage by doing stage = new Stage(); but it just assigns second empty stage to the canvas, should use stage.removeAllChildren() instead

Comment: put your answer as proper answer and mark it correct

Comment: having the same issue, removing the button but the area is still clickable
have u found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

what did you do the clear the stage?

```
stage.removeAllChildren()
```

Make sure your stage has no children by checking:

```
console.log(stage.getNumChildren());
```

if you want to remove the onPress listener, I simply do to:

```
container.onPress=null;
```

It may not be the best way to disable it, but it works for me.